# Which is called first?? onResume or OnLocationChanged override method?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-asynctask, locationlistener

In my fragment class I have implemented LocationListener for knowing my current location but i need to know which method is being created first is it the @override public void OnLocationChanged(Location location) or @override public void onResume()???

-thanks

Comment: You can test that by yourself, or find the answer by searching.

Comment: put breakpoints on both, debug your app, and it'll tell you which is being created first.

Comment: The question is impossible to answer since there is no relationship between the two.  They are asynchronous events.  If you are relying on one happening before or after the other, then your design is wrong.  Please edit your question and explain **why** you need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calling of `onLocationChanged()` is not dependent on the calling of `onResume()`. It all depends on how your code is set up and when you actually change your location.

Due to this, you must put `System.out.println()` lines in the relevant parts of your code to verify when the methods are being called.

Hopefully this is of help.

Comment: @Aeons No problem, and don't worry about the downvotes, when I was new to programming all of my stackoverflow questions got downvoted heaps! :)